# is if na restart count

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is the same as this[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286834/count-number-of-occurences-in-different-timeline/63288275#63288275) but I want to preserve the date. Please read that first.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(mydate = as.Date(c("2019-05-11 23:01:00", "2019-05-11 23:02:00", "2019-05-11 23:03:00", "2019-05-11 23:04:00",
                                "2019-05-12 23:05:00", "2019-05-12 23:06:00", "2019-05-12 23:07:00", "2019-05-12 23:08:00",
                                "2019-05-13 23:09:00", "2019-05-13 23:10:00", "2019-05-13 23:11:00", "2019-05-13 23:12:00",
                                "2019-05-14 23:13:00", "2019-05-14 23:14:00", "2019-05-14 23:15:00", "2019-05-14 23:16:00",
                                "2019-05-15 23:17:00", "2019-05-15 23:18:00", "2019-05-15 23:19:00", "2019-05-15 23:20:00")),
               myval = c(0, NA, 1500, 1500,
                         1500, 1500, NA, 0,
                         0, 0, 1100, 1100,
                         1100, 0, 200, 200,
                         1100, 1100, 1100, 0
               ))

# just replace values [0,1] with NA
df$myval[df$myval >= 0 & df$myval <= 1] <- NA

df <- df %>%
    group_by(myval) %>%
    mutate(counts = sum(myval == myval)) %>%
    mutate(result = (myval  / counts))
```

Right now the result is:

```
mydate     myval counts result
   <date>     <dbl>  <int>  <dbl>
 1 2019-05-11    NA     NA    NA 
 2 2019-05-11    NA     NA    NA 
 3 2019-05-11  1500      4   375 
 4 2019-05-11  1500      4   375 
 5 2019-05-12  1500      4   375 
 6 2019-05-12  1500      4   375 
 7 2019-05-12    NA     NA    NA 
 8 2019-05-12    NA     NA    NA 
 9 2019-05-13    NA     NA    NA 
10 2019-05-13    NA     NA    NA 
11 2019-05-13  1100      6   183.
12 2019-05-13  1100      6   183.
13 2019-05-14  1100      6   183.
14 2019-05-14    NA     NA    NA 
15 2019-05-14   200      2   100 
16 2019-05-14   200      2   100 
17 2019-05-15  1100      6   183.
18 2019-05-15  1100      6   183.
19 2019-05-15  1100      6   183.
20 2019-05-15    NA     NA    NA
```

I want to preserve the above dataframe, wth the dates column  and the correct result.

I need somehow to restart the counting if after/before a value a NA exists.

So, for 1100 , I must have count 3 two times and not count 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create groups with `data.table` `rleid` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(myval)) %>%
  mutate(counts = n(), 
         result= myval/counts)


#   mydate     myval   grp counts result
#   <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>  <dbl>
# 1 2019-05-11    NA     1      2    NA 
# 2 2019-05-11    NA     1      2    NA 
# 3 2019-05-11  1500     2      4   375 
# 4 2019-05-11  1500     2      4   375 
# 5 2019-05-12  1500     2      4   375 
# 6 2019-05-12  1500     2      4   375 
# 7 2019-05-12    NA     3      4    NA 
# 8 2019-05-12    NA     3      4    NA 
# 9 2019-05-13    NA     3      4    NA 
#10 2019-05-13    NA     3      4    NA 
#11 2019-05-13  1100     4      3   367.
#12 2019-05-13  1100     4      3   367.
#13 2019-05-14  1100     4      3   367.
#14 2019-05-14    NA     5      1    NA 
#15 2019-05-14   200     6      2   100 
#16 2019-05-14   200     6      2   100 
#17 2019-05-15  1100     7      3   367.
#18 2019-05-15  1100     7      3   367.
#19 2019-05-15  1100     7      3   367.
#20 2019-05-15    NA     8      1    NA
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. I wanted to ask if it is easy to divide every value by the previous count, not itself. So, for the first value (1500) we will have NA because there is no other value before that. Then, we will divide 1100 by 4 because the count of previous value (1500) is 4. Then, we will divide  200 by 3 because the previous value (1100) has count 3. Last, divide 1100 by 2 because 200 has count 2. I hope it is clear! I tried to use shift/lag but can't succeed!

Comment: I think that will take a very different approach. Would you ask that as a new question?

Comment: Hello, I started a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63335286/count-rows-from-every-previous-value)

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, counts := .N, rleid(myval)][, result := myval/counts]
```