# count rows from every previous value

Tags: r, dplyr

This question is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300030/is-if-na-restart-count) but this time I want to divide every value by the previous count, not itself. So, for the first value (1500) we will have NA because there is no other value before that. Then, we will divide 1100 by 4 because the count of previous value (1500) is 4. Then, we will divide 200 by 3 because the previous value (1100) has count 3. Last, divide 1100 by 2 because 200 has count 2. I tried to use shift/lag but can't succeed!

This is the code that divides every value with its own count.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble(mydate = as.Date(c("2019-05-11 23:01:00", "2019-05-11 23:02:00", "2019-05-11 23:03:00", "2019-05-11 23:04:00",
                                "2019-05-12 23:05:00", "2019-05-12 23:06:00", "2019-05-12 23:07:00", "2019-05-12 23:08:00",
                                "2019-05-13 23:09:00", "2019-05-13 23:10:00", "2019-05-13 23:11:00", "2019-05-13 23:12:00",
                                "2019-05-14 23:13:00", "2019-05-14 23:14:00", "2019-05-14 23:15:00", "2019-05-14 23:16:00",
                                "2019-05-15 23:17:00", "2019-05-15 23:18:00", "2019-05-15 23:19:00", "2019-05-15 23:20:00")),
               myval = c(0, NA, 1500, 1500,
                         1500, 1500, NA, 0,
                         0, 0, 1100, 1100,
                         1100, 0, 200, 200,
                         1100, 1100, 1100, 0
               ))

# just replace values [0,1] with NA
df$myval[df$myval >= 0 & df$myval <= 1] <- NA


df <- df %>%
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(myval)) %>%
  mutate(counts = n(), 
         result= myval/counts)


#   mydate     myval   grp counts result
#   <date>     <dbl> <int>  <int>  <dbl>
# 1 2019-05-11    NA     1      2    NA 
# 2 2019-05-11    NA     1      2    NA 
# 3 2019-05-11  1500     2      4   375 
# 4 2019-05-11  1500     2      4   375 
# 5 2019-05-12  1500     2      4   375 
# 6 2019-05-12  1500     2      4   375 
# 7 2019-05-12    NA     3      4    NA 
# 8 2019-05-12    NA     3      4    NA 
# 9 2019-05-13    NA     3      4    NA 
#10 2019-05-13    NA     3      4    NA 
#11 2019-05-13  1100     4      3   367.
#12 2019-05-13  1100     4      3   367.
#13 2019-05-14  1100     4      3   367.
#14 2019-05-14    NA     5      1    NA 
#15 2019-05-14   200     6      2   100 
#16 2019-05-14   200     6      2   100 
#17 2019-05-15  1100     7      3   367.
#18 2019-05-15  1100     7      3   367.
#19 2019-05-15  1100     7      3   367.
#20 2019-05-15    NA     8      1    NA
```

I want to preserve the above dataframe, with the dates column and the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
library(dplyr)
#Create a group number
df1 <- df %>% mutate(grp = data.table::rleid(myval))

df1 %>%
  #Keep only non-NA value
  filter(!is.na(myval)) %>%
  #count occurence of each grp
  count(grp, name = 'count') %>%
  #Shift the count to the previous group
  mutate(count = lag(count)) %>%
  #Join with the original data
  right_join(df1, by = 'grp') %>%
  #divide the count to get final result
  mutate(result = myval/count) %>%
  arrange(grp)
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
#     grp count mydate     myval result
#   <int> <int> <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1    NA 2019-05-11    NA   NA  
# 2     1    NA 2019-05-11    NA   NA  
# 3     2    NA 2019-05-11  1500   NA  
# 4     2    NA 2019-05-11  1500   NA  
# 5     2    NA 2019-05-12  1500   NA  
# 6     2    NA 2019-05-12  1500   NA  
# 7     3    NA 2019-05-12    NA   NA  
# 8     3    NA 2019-05-12    NA   NA  
# 9     3    NA 2019-05-13    NA   NA  
#10     3    NA 2019-05-13    NA   NA  
#11     4     4 2019-05-13  1100  275  
#12     4     4 2019-05-13  1100  275  
#13     4     4 2019-05-14  1100  275  
#14     5    NA 2019-05-14    NA   NA  
#15     6     3 2019-05-14   200   66.7
#16     6     3 2019-05-14   200   66.7
#17     7     2 2019-05-15  1100  550  
#18     7     2 2019-05-15  1100  550  
#19     7     2 2019-05-15  1100  550  
#20     8    NA 2019-05-15    NA   NA
```