# do not count zeros but keep group number

Tags: r, dplyr

I am grouping data based on mdo value and counting the instances of these values.
I then use the previous count to do some computations.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(mydate = as.Date(c("2019-05-11 23:01:00", "2019-05-11 23:02:00", "2019-05-11 23:03:00", "2019-05-11 23:04:00",
                                "2019-05-12 23:05:00", "2019-05-12 23:06:00", "2019-05-12 23:07:00", "2019-05-12 23:08:00",
                                "2019-05-13 23:09:00", "2019-05-13 23:10:00", "2019-05-13 23:11:00", "2019-05-13 23:12:00",
                                "2019-05-14 23:13:00", "2019-05-14 23:14:00", "2019-05-14 23:15:00", "2019-05-14 23:16:00",
                                "2019-05-15 23:17:00", "2019-05-15 23:18:00", "2019-05-15 23:19:00", "2019-05-15 23:20:00",
                                "2019-05-15 23:21:00", "2019-05-15 23:22:00", "2019-05-15 23:23:00", "2019-05-15 23:24:00",
                                "2019-05-15 23:25:00")),
             mdo = c(1500, 1500, 1500, 1500,
                     1500, 1500, NA, 0,
                     0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1100, 1100,
                     1100, 200, 200, 200,200,
                     1100, 1100, 1100, 0
             ))


#Create a group number
df1 <- df %>% mutate(grp = data.table::rleid(mdo))

df1 <- df1 %>%
    #Keep only non-NA value
    filter(!is.na(mdo)) %>%
    #count occurence of each grp
    count(grp, name = 'count') %>%
    #Shift the count to the previous group
    mutate(count = lag(count)) %>%
    #Join with the original data
    right_join(df1, by = 'grp')
```

Right now , it counts zeros. I don't want to count zeros but I want to keep them in a different group.

I want something like:

`count(ifelse(mdo != 0, grp, NA), name='count') %>%`

but this gives:

`Error: by can't contain join column grp which is missing from LHS`

The result right now is:

```
 grp count mydate       mdo
   <int> <int> <date>     <dbl>
 1     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 2     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 3     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 4     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 5     1    NA 2019-05-12  1500
 6     1    NA 2019-05-12  1500
 7     2    NA 2019-05-12    NA
 8     3     6 2019-05-12     0
 9     3     6 2019-05-13     0
10     3     6 2019-05-13     0
11     4    NA 2019-05-13    NA
12     4    NA 2019-05-13    NA
13     4    NA 2019-05-14    NA
14     4    NA 2019-05-14    NA
15     5     3 2019-05-14  1100
16     5     3 2019-05-14  1100
17     5     3 2019-05-15  1100
18     6     3 2019-05-15   200
19     6     3 2019-05-15   200
20     6     3 2019-05-15   200
21     6     3 2019-05-15   200
22     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
23     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
24     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
25     8     3 2019-05-15     0
```

the result I want:

```
 grp count mydate       mdo
   <int> <int> <date>     <dbl>
 1     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 2     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 3     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 4     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 5     1    NA 2019-05-12  1500
 6     1    NA 2019-05-12  1500
 7     2    NA 2019-05-12    NA
 8     3     6 2019-05-12     0
 9     3     6 2019-05-13     0
10     3     6 2019-05-13     0
11     4    NA 2019-05-13    NA
12     4    NA 2019-05-13    NA
13     4    NA 2019-05-14    NA
14     4    NA 2019-05-14    NA
15     5    NA 2019-05-14  1100
16     5    NA 2019-05-14  1100
17     5    NA 2019-05-15  1100
18     6     3 2019-05-15   200
19     6     3 2019-05-15   200
20     6     3 2019-05-15   200
21     6     3 2019-05-15   200
22     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
23     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
24     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
25     8     3 2019-05-15     0
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the given example?

Comment: @RonakShah:I updated post, thanks

Comment: So `count` only in group 5 is changed. Why `count` in group 5 should be `NA` ?

Comment: @RonakShah: Because later when I will divide 1100 by the count, if I leave it 3 counts it will make the division. But, because mdo was zero , I want the division not to take place, I want to set zero there. (of course this is an issue, how to set it zero)

Comment: `mdo` is not 0 in group 5 it is 1100.

Comment: @RonakShah:Yes, but the division takes place with the previous count [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63335286/count-rows-from-every-previous-value]

Comment: I don't get the desired logic for your output. You want the count for group 5 to be `NA` because `mdo` of group 3 is `NA`, which is the group before group 5 not being `NA` in mdo?!

Comment: @MartinGal: I want count for group 5 to be NA because mdo of group 3 is zero. Generally, I want not to count the zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100 % sure, how your underlying logic works, but you could try the following steps using `dplyr`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(mdo)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(count=ifelse(mdo==0, NA_integer_, n()), .groups="drop") %>%
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(count=lag(count)) %>%
  right_join(df1, by="grp") %>%
  arrange(grp, mydate)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 25 x 4
     grp count mydate       mdo
   <int> <int> <date>     <dbl>
 1     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 2     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 3     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 4     1    NA 2019-05-11  1500
 5     1    NA 2019-05-12  1500
 6     1    NA 2019-05-12  1500
 7     2    NA 2019-05-12    NA
 8     3     6 2019-05-12     0
 9     3     6 2019-05-13     0
10     3     6 2019-05-13     0
11     4    NA 2019-05-13    NA
12     4    NA 2019-05-13    NA
13     4    NA 2019-05-14    NA
14     4    NA 2019-05-14    NA
15     5    NA 2019-05-14  1100
16     5    NA 2019-05-14  1100
17     5    NA 2019-05-15  1100
18     6     3 2019-05-15   200
19     6     3 2019-05-15   200
20     6     3 2019-05-15   200
21     6     3 2019-05-15   200
22     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
23     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
24     7     4 2019-05-15  1100
25     8     3 2019-05-15     0
```

---

#### Data

```r
structure(list(mydate = structure(c(18027, 18027, 18027, 18027, 
18028, 18028, 18028, 18028, 18029, 18029, 18029, 18029, 18030, 
18030, 18030, 18030, 18031, 18031, 18031, 18031, 18031, 18031, 
18031, 18031, 18031), class = "Date"), mdo = c(1500, 1500, 1500, 
1500, 1500, 1500, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1100, 1100, 1100, 
200, 200, 200, 200, 1100, 1100, 1100, 0), grp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It gives `Error: Column count must be length 1 not 6`

Comment: That's odd. I used the data shown above as `df1` and I'm able to run the code without an error.

Comment: Maybe some version dependence? I can't find a way to correct this.

Comment: What's your `dplyr` version? I'm using `1.0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Before joining you can keep the value of `mdo` in `summarise` and if the previous value in `mdo` is 0, turn the `count` value to `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(!is.na(mdo)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(mdo = first(mdo), 
            count = n()) %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(lag(mdo) == 0, NA, lag(count))) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c('grp', 'mdo'))  %>%
  arrange(grp)

#   grp  mdo count     mydate
#1    1 1500    NA 2019-05-11
#2    1 1500    NA 2019-05-11
#3    1 1500    NA 2019-05-11
#4    1 1500    NA 2019-05-11
#5    1 1500    NA 2019-05-12
#6    1 1500    NA 2019-05-12
#7    2   NA    NA 2019-05-12
#8    3    0     6 2019-05-12
#9    3    0     6 2019-05-13
#10   3    0     6 2019-05-13
#11   4   NA    NA 2019-05-13
#12   4   NA    NA 2019-05-13
#13   4   NA    NA 2019-05-14
#14   4   NA    NA 2019-05-14
#15   5 1100    NA 2019-05-14
#16   5 1100    NA 2019-05-14
#17   5 1100    NA 2019-05-15
#18   6  200     3 2019-05-15
#19   6  200     3 2019-05-15
#20   6  200     3 2019-05-15
#21   6  200     3 2019-05-15
#22   7 1100     4 2019-05-15
#23   7 1100     4 2019-05-15
#24   7 1100     4 2019-05-15
#25   8    0     3 2019-05-15
```